# How can I unit test an EmailAction from ActionMailer.Net using RhinoMocks and MSTest?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to write a unit test for a simple EmailAction in ActionEmailer.Net but I am struggling to figure out how to do it. This is what I have so far.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEmailTest()
    {
        //// Arrange

        var AutoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<EmailController>(MockMode.AAA);

        EmailController MockEmailController = AutoMocker.ClassUnderTest;

        var MockHttpContext = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();

        MockEmailController.HttpContextBase = MockHttpContext;

        var MockSender = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMailSender>();
        MockEmailController.MailSender = MockSender;


        ////// Act

        var Result = MockEmailController.TestEmail();


        //// Assert

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(Result, typeof(EmailResult));
    }
```

However It fails to execute TestEmail as it says that an object is set to null, but doesn't tell me which one!

All help appreciated.

Cheers Mike

Comment: The object that is null is httpcontext.current or something.  I don't know how to get round this though.  I'm trying to figure out this also.